# Pandas custom date interval/frequency

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to convert a Pandas series to a period index. I found several useful time intervals already (quarterly, yearly), but I'd like to expand on this and have 2-yearly and 5-yearly intervals.

Providing a string to the `to_period` method such as `'2Y'` or `'5Y'` raises a `ValueError('Only mult == 1 supported')`.

```
period_width = 'Q' # 'Y'
df['period'] = df['date'].dt.to_period(period_width)
```

How can I create custom intervals?

**Update**

The result should behave the same as `to_period()`.

```
In [2]:

import datetime
import pandas as pd
​
df = pd.DataFrame({
        'date': [
            datetime.datetime(2010, 2, 2), 
            datetime.datetime(2010, 2, 5), 
            datetime.datetime(2011, 2, 2), 
            datetime.datetime(2012, 3, 5)
        ]
    })
period_width = 'Y'
df['period'] = df['date'].dt.to_period(period_width)
df
Out[2]:
date    period
0   2010-02-02  2010
1   2010-02-05  2010
2   2011-02-02  2011
3   2012-03-05  2012
In [3]:

df.dtypes
Out[3]:
date      datetime64[ns]
period            object
dtype: object
```

Comment: Looks like you just want to year part of the date. With pandas you can simply do `df.date.year` to get that. Or am I missing the point?

Answer (score 1):

Well, to create 5 year gaps you might just use the `datetime` module.

That would look something like this to create 5 year intervals of Jan 1 starting in the year 2000:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as datetime

five_y = pd.Series([datetime.datetime(Year, 1, 1).date() for Year in xrange(2000, 2100, 5)])

In [2]: five_y
Out[2]: 
0     2000-01-01
1     2005-01-01
2     2010-01-01
3     2015-01-01
4     2020-01-01
5     2025-01-01
6     2030-01-01
7     2035-01-01
8     2040-01-01
9     2045-01-01
10    2050-01-01
11    2055-01-01
12    2060-01-01
13    2065-01-01
14    2070-01-01
15    2075-01-01
16    2080-01-01
17    2085-01-01
18    2090-01-01
19    2095-01-01
dtype: object
```

Comment: This isn't the same, I am afraid. `to_period` doesn't require a start and end date.

Comment: So what does the output look like, for my information?

Comment: See my update. I'm interested in using some Pandas functions for this that behave the same `as to_period` as there's some postprocessing done (grouping, pivot table, index) which I don't want to break.

Comment: Do you actually care that the object in the period column is a `Period` object? If not then could you not just create a function to put them in bins and have strings in the period column indicating the bin? Then you could do groupie operations etc. on them which is presumably where you are heading...